# Disable ALL password prompts in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, root

I FREQUENTLY mess with system/hidden files in `/Library`, `/System`, `/bin`, etc. and I'm tired of constantly being prompted for my (20+ Alphanumeric character) password. I'd like to have my "Administer" user account have all permission like `root`. I know it's a "security" hazard, but my network is locked down, drive is file vault 2 encrypted, and password is crazy complex (good luck dictionary brute-forcers). I can run Finder as root, but how can I make it the default behavior in 10.8/10.9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Do It Yourself: Option 1

Open a Finder window in Column View. Choose `Go To Folder` from the `Go` menu. In the sheet that comes down, type `/System/Library/CoreServices`. You'll see two Finders there. Click on one of them (just one click!) and make sure it doesn't say "Classic Application" in the preview pane. If it doesn't, then that's the one you want. Hold <kbd>Option</kbd> and drag it to the desktop (because you want to duplicate it).

Now rename that app to `RootFinder` or something. Move it to your `/Applications` directory. That's all the setup; the only part you have to repeat is from here on in.

Open the terminal. Type:

```
    cd /Applications
    sudo open -a RootFinder.app
```

Enter your admin password at the prompt. Note that your desktop picture will change, and a new default Finder window will pop up. Your original Finder windows or other running apps won't be affected, however. Now, you **cannot** move files from one Finder to the other, but as long as you're using only the root finder (opening new windows will open them as root finder, obviously), you have full root access to the bowels of your system and you can browse directories and copy/move files much more easily.

To get back to where you were, open the Terminal again. Type `ps auxc | grep Finder` and then `sudo kill [PID]` and enter the PID of the Finder. The Finder will automatically relaunch in your original account, and your desktop picture will change back.

**Source**: [Create a GUI Finder with root access](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20010514171224297)

### Third Party App: Option 2

Would you be interested in [LaunchAsRoot](http://www.limit-point.com/Utilities/LaunchAsRoot.html)?

From their website,

### How to use

Drag the application (or a document) you wish to launch as root on top of the `LaunchAsRoot` application icon in the Finder. You will presented with an authentication dialog. Enter the name and password of an administrator to allow the application to be launched by LaunchAsRoot. LaunchAsRoot quits after launching the application.

### How to use Service:

Control-click on the application (or a document) in the Finder and select "Launch As Root" from the Services contextual submenu. You will presented with an authentication dialog. Enter the name and password of an administrator to allow the application to be launched by LaunchAsRoot. LaunchAsRoot quits after launching the application.

Comment: Not as automatic as I would have liked s i'll keep looking. I might settle for this soon though