# How do I disable ALL password prompts in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, password

Have searched far and wide with no answers.  I want to never enter any passwords again for my entire OS X experience (except internet passwords, of course).  Please do not answer "it's a bad idea"; I know the risks, and they are mine to take.

Comment: [Check out this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/100018/65956)

Answer (score 1):

Logging in as the *root* user will negate most administrative password prompts, but this is highly dangerous for your system's security.

A better idea, though not by much is to change your login password to nothing, so when you are prompted for a password, you simply press Enter, and the procedure begins.

Comment: Still, it's something I'd never attempt, but I see what you mean.